# How can I set up Nginx as reverse proxy?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, nginx

I have a virtual server on Digital Ocean and inside this server I have 2 applications: Laravel app in path /var/www/api with proxy_pass http://localhost:8000  and a react js app in path /var/www/spa
with proxy_pass http://localhost:3000.

How can configure the Nginx server block for the Laravel app and the React app ?

The problem is the two apps don't work on localhost:8000 and localhost:300. If I run command `php artisan serve` on
Laravel or `npm start` on React, the two apps work but I can not use those commands in production. I want the Nginx server block configuration to work without using command `php artisan serve` or `npm start`. I want the two application work in production on port 8000 and 3000 on localhost and nginx as reverse proxy.

I read many links on internet to solve the problem but they don't work. What can I try next?

Comment: For the Laravel app you need to use the php-fpm (php fastcgi process manager) and a fastcgi configuration (example [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)). For your react code you would typically run something like vite or mix to build the resources for production and have nginx serve them as static files

Comment: Thank you so much  apokryfos .Could you please help me more bymodifying  this server block below which doesnt work :server { // this block for laravel app backend 
listen 80:
server_name  api.example.com  ;
location /{
  proxy_pass  http://localhost:8000;
}




server { // this block for react app front ened
listen 80:
server_name  example.com  www.example.com;
location /{
  proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000;
}